# What is the default size used by logrotate?

Tags: logrotate

I looked at the man pages, searched here, googled, etc.

Does anyone know the default size used by logrotate?

What reference can you cite stating the default size?

I know I can set size specifically in my config files.

Comment: isn't it mentioned in file `/etc/logrotate.conf`?

Comment: akubot: Try asking this on superuser.com. SiB: Not on my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I know, there is no default size for logrotate, no need to waste time on this，set the value yourself in config file.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a default size, because it's an optional flag. logrotate will rotate based on certain criteria that you give it, e.g., file size or time period (`daily`, `weekly`, etc). So it's not that it has a default file size (except maybe something like `size 0`), it's just not a precondition for a file being rotated.